# Algorithm of resizing rectangles but keeping the distances between them

Tags: algorithm, resize

i am looking for an algorithm that will resize all rectangles to new width, height of all objects on the scene but keep the distances between them. Is that possible ?

[image: tree structure]

The anchor for each rectangle is Top-Left (0,0). Thank you.

Comment: In the x axis, x_end = x_start + width decreased /2

Comment: Q1) Do you mean 'distance' as the minimum distance (i.e. between the closest points), or somehow along axes?
Q2) Are your rectangles always have edges parallel to the axes?

Because in general case the answer is no.

Comment: I want the composition of the stage to look the same after resizing, probably not possible to keep all the distances as constant. But visually it looks possible, starting from the top moving the rectangles left and down row by row. I mean distance between the rectangles like D = view1.end_x - view2.start_x

Comment: So if you have two rectangles, with one 10 pixels to the right of the other, you want to increase the size of both rectangles and have the distance between them remain 10 pixels? In other words, you want to scale the rectangles, but not scale the white space?

Comment: Correct, It's like for x axis : [x] [x] => [xx] [xx]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the algorithm, not sure if its the best or optimized.

Basically finding depths and then sorting but depth adding extra or x multiplied by depth. The algorithm should be applied for Y as well.

1.First get the most left unmarked element. (mark when make depths)
2.Find all siblings top/bottom (sibling element which is from pos.x-width to pos.x+width)
3.Mark elements depth.
4.Repeat

Using stacks instead of recursion code is not completely DRY.

```
vt.iccode.DrawScene.prototype.ClearDepths = function () {
    for (var i=0,ii=this.nodes.length;i<ii;i++) {
        var node = this.nodes[i];
        node.ClearDepths();
    }
};

/*
 * @private
 */
vt.iccode.DrawScene.prototype.MarkTopSiblings = function(node_start, depth) {
    var stack = new Array();
    stack.push(node_start);

    while (stack.length > 0) {
        var node = stack[stack.length - 1];
        stack.splice(stack.length - 1, 1);

        console.info("marking top :"+node.name+" depth ->"+depth);
        node.depth_x = depth;

        var pos = node.GetPosition();
        var size = node.GetSize();
        var next_node = this.GetClosestElementWithinBounds(node, pos.x - size.width, pos.x + size.width, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, pos.y);

        if (next_node) {
            stack.push(next_node);
        }
    }
};

vt.iccode.DrawScene.prototype.MarkBottomSiblings = function(node_start, depth) {
    var stack = new Array();
    stack.push(node_start);

    while (stack.length > 0) {
        var node = stack[stack.length - 1];
        stack.splice(stack.length - 1, 1);

        console.info("marking bottom :"+node.name+" depth ->"+depth);
        node.depth_x = depth;

        var pos = node.GetPosition();
        var size = node.GetSize();
        var next_node = this.GetClosestElementWithinBounds(node, pos.x - size.width, pos.x + size.width, pos.y + size.height, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
        if (next_node) {
            stack.push(next_node);
        }
    }
};

vt.iccode.DrawScene.prototype.GetMostLeftUnmarked = function() {
    var s_x = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var best_match = null;

    for (var i=0,ii=0;i<this.nodes.length;i++) {
        var node = this.nodes[i];
        var pos = node.GetPosition();

        if (goog.isNull(node.depth_x) && pos.x < s_x) {
            s_x = pos.x;
            best_match = node;
        }
    }

    return best_match;
};

vt.iccode.DrawScene.prototype.GetClosestElementWithinBounds = function(node, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max) {
    var found = new Array();

    for (var i = 0, ii = this.nodes.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var node_test = this.nodes[i];
        var pos = node_test.GetPosition();

        if (pos.x >= x_min && pos.x <= x_max && pos.y >= y_min && pos.y <= y_max && goog.isNull(node_test.depth_x) && goog.isNull(node_test.depth_y)) {
            found.push(node_test);
        }
    }

    var s_distance = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var best_match = null;

    for (var i = 0, ii = found.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var node_test = found[i];
        var dist = node.FindDistanceBetweenAnchorPoints(node_test);
        if (dist < s_distance) {
            s_distance = dist;
            best_match = node_test;
        }
    }
    ;

    return best_match;
};
```

Use like :

```
this.ClearDepths();

var most_left_node = this.nodes[0];
var stack = new Array();
stack.push(most_left_node);
var depth_x = 0;

while(stack.length>0) {
    var node = stack[stack.length - 1];
    stack.splice(stack.length - 1, 1);

    this.MarkBottomSiblings(node,depth_x);
    this.MarkTopSiblings(node, depth_x);

    var node_next = this.GetMostLeftUnmarked();
    if (!goog.isNull(node_next)) {
        // 
        console.info(node_next.name);
        stack.push(node_next);
        // return;
    }

    depth_x++;
}
```

After we know the depths we can move by x vise versa for y.